# Effect of eval('?><?php') in symfony source

Tags: php, symfony

Line 3083 of `var/cache/dev/classes.php` is as follows in my Symfony project :

```
eval('?>'.$content);
```

When I  view it my debugger, I see that `$content` is set to `"<?php"`. So the command executed here is `eval('?><?php');`, and I presume
it must just exit and re-enter php. But my stack trace says :

```
at Symfony\Component\Routing\Router->generate('openid/server', array(), '1')
in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Extension/RoutingExtension.php line 45

at Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Extension\RoutingExtension->getPath('openid/server')
in var/cache/dev/classes.php(3083) : eval()'d code line 106

at __TwigTemplate_796eabb7be58900d71ef26da18735885230dda71cde4d67f04a324145cd5ea80->doDisplay(array('app' => object(AppVariable)), array())
in var/cache/dev/classes.php line 4759
```

Line 106 of which file has been executed ?

Comment: Aside from its many other dangers, one of the worst aspects of using eval is the complete lack of any useful error messaging when it fails

Comment: [Little known fact](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php#118827) : an opening tag for a php script actually needs to be followed by some sort of whitespace character (newline, space, tab) or it will throw a syntax error. With that in mind, what happens when you have `$content` set to `<?php ` with a space following the opening tag (so that the eval'd string would be `'?><?php '`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something I just learned the other day:

A [PHP start tag actually must be followed by a newline character](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php#118827), or it will throw a syntax error.

So this code:

```
'?><?php'
```

is not syntactically correct. But this would be:

```
'?><?php ' // followed by space
```

and this would be:

```
'?><?php    ' // followed by tab
```

and this would be:

```
'?><?php
' // followed by newline or carriage return
```

So for your test code, what is the outcome if you set `$content` to `'<?php '`, so that a single-space character follows the opening tag? Or change the eval (still a pretty dodgy bit of code, on its own, no matter what) to :

```
eval('?>'.$content. PHP_EOL);
```

so that a newline is always ensured to be added to the end?

Comment: Not knowing this mandatory space issue, I din't check precisely  in my debugger if the contents of $content has trailing spaces at the end or not. In any case, I added PHP_EOL as you suggested, and that changed nothing. Thanks for the "little-known" tip anyway

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell you why there is an `eval` but maybe try to clear the cache and try it again?

```
php app/console cache:clear
```

Comment: didn't solve my problem, but this is definitely a useful random hack to try when one is at a loss what to do. Thanks